# Runtime overlays android with appcompat

Tags: android, overlay, oms, rro

I want to make runtime overlays for an application that uses appcompat but I can't get it to work.

I followed this [Example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-theme-android-with-the-runtime-resource-overlay-framework--cms-29708)

First:
I created and android application that i want to overlay. I'm trying to overlay the string in textview "Hello World" to be "Hello World overlay!"

**The App code snaps**

Main activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Main activity layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello_world"
 />

</FrameLayout>
```

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="com.example.app">

 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
     android:supportsRtl="true">
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
     </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

App theme:

```xml
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

String resources

```xml
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
```

Till this point the code is working fine :)

Then I create the overlay project that include the overlay resource.

**The Overlay project code snaps:**

Manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.overlay">

    <overlay
        android:priority="1"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.app"/>
    <application android:hasCode="false"/>

</manifest>
```

The string resources that i want to overlay them in runtime

```xml
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World Overlay!</string>
```

I built and installed the apk.And i can find it as overlay when i'm using  `adb shell cmd overlay list`

Once I enabled the overlay using `adb shell cmd overlay enable --user 0 com.example.overlay` I got this crash.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:57)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2026)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:57) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5238) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2026) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**However, I'm using appcompat theme on the application and the overlay.**

Any ideas how can I make it work?

**NOTE: I tried to run it on Android 9 and Android 10**

Update 1:
when i extend from Activity instead of AppCompatActivity it's working fine without any problems

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your RRO module you should remove the dependency on AppCompat and the one one MaterialComponents.

Answer (score -2):

You can use my [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark) in there I tried to do that in a very reusable way so that you can do an overlay with less code.
Here is documentation on how to use it in [Java](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-java) and [Kotlin](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-kotlin). First, initialize it from an activity from where you want to show the watermark-

```
AppWaterMarkBuilder.doConfigure()
                .setAppCompatActivity(MainActivity.this)
                .setWatermarkProperty(R.layout.layout_water_mark)
                .showWatermarkAfterConfig();
```

Then you can hide and show it from anywhere in your app -

```
  /* For hiding the watermark*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.hideWatermark() 

  /* For showing the watermark*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.showWatermark()
```

The gif -

[image: preview]